# what are the alternatives (OSS,commercial) for virtual machine life-cycle management? 

Tags: linux, virtualization, vmware-esxi, xen, cloud-computing

likes of VMware lab manager:

desired feature list:

- Self-Service: rapid-delpoy-VMs
- configuration management: clone, snapshot VM

good to have:

1. hypervisor agnostic
2. storage lease
3. user access - role based
4. cap on resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if you could use something like openstack to handle this?